# navigate to different pages based on successful completion of a Google form

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sites

I'am using a Google Spreadsheet Form to register visitors to my Google Site before I permit them to take a tour which may include 3 to 10 webpages.

How can I verify that the form was filled out successfully - all required fields entered before launching the first page of the tour.

Comment: You can try to use Google Apps Script to make the form and subsequently the redirection to other pages.

Answer (score 0):

Put the tour link on the forms sent confirmation page. Cheers